# Swift Promises - Reload Data method is not binding the data

Tags: swift

I'm using promises to retrieve information some methods via JSON. I'm filling the information with the function:

I'm trying to set those records in my TableView with:

```
@IBOutlet weak var usersTableView: UITableView!

var dataSource: [UserResponse]? {
    didSet {
        self.usersTableView.reloadData()
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    loadFriends()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

func loadFriends() {
    //UserService.getFriends()
    let (request, promise) = UserService.getFriends()

    promise.then { user in
        self.dataSource = user
        }.catch{
            error in
            SCLAlertView().showError("Error", subTitle: error.localizedDescription)
    }

}
```

But is returning the error:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

How I can fix this error?

Comment: Looks like either `usersTableView` is `nil` when you call `reloadData()` on it, or `promise` is an implicitly unwrapped optional and is `nil`. Which line does the error show on?

Comment: the line is `self.usersTableView.reloadData()` , but the promise `user in
        self.dataSource = user` has the correct values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `usersTableView` is an implicitly unwrapped optional (`UITableView!`). When you call the `dataSource` setter, the `didSet` property observer tries to call `reloadData()` on `usersTableView`, but it is `nil`, so you get a crash - you cannot call methods on `nil`.

It looks like you haven't connected the outlet to your `usersTableView` property in your storyboard. Alternatively, you're setting it to `nil` somewhere else in your code. This could be happening automatically if `usersTableView` isn't part of your view hierarchy when the view controller is loaded, since it is a `weak` variable, but I expect you have added it as a subview in the storyboard?

Comment: yes, it was added in a subview, and the `usersTableView` was created as `IBOutlet` using the standard method (control + right click). This is all my conde, I'm not setting it `nil` anywhere, I going to try recreating the sceneario to be totally sure if the outlet is binded to the storyboard - @Stuart

Comment: No need to reset anything. Just select the view controller in the storyboard and look at the connections inspector panel (on the right). It will show an outlet for `usersTableView`, and the dot next to it should be filled in. If not, drag from the empty dot over to the table view to connect it. You can also see if the state of the connect in your source code - just to the left of the `@IBOutlet weak var usersTableView: UITableView!` line, there will be a dot in the gutter - filled if connected, empty otherwise.

Comment: Yes, are connected @Stuart (and only have 1 connection for the outles)

Comment: @MrMins How are you initialising your view controller?